# Excel - vlookup value - combination of2 columns (without concat) from another sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I want to write kind of formula (look-up) where i can match and bring data from another sheet using combination of 2 columns without concatenation. I am doing using following formula at the moment:

```
+VLOOKUP(A1&B1,'other_sheet'!A:D,4,0)
```

where Colomn A in other sheet in concat of B1 and C1 (B1&C1)

However, my intention is to to get same result without doing any concat as you can see in below pic:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

[image]

For microsoft365:

```
=FILTER(G$2:G$9,(E$2:E$9=A2)*(F$2:F$9=B2),"")
```

Drag down. Or if you don't want to drag down the formula and `BYROW()` is available:

```
=BYROW(A2:B6,LAMBDA(a,FILTER(G2:G9,MMULT(--(E2:F9=a),{1,1})=2)))
```

---

For older versions of Excel try:

```
=INDEX(G$2:G$9,MATCH(1,INDEX((E$2:E$9=A2)*(F$2:F$9=B2),),0))
```

Or:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/((E$2:E$9=A2)*(F$2:F$9=B2)),G$2:G$9)
```

Drag down.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you can do:

```
=INDEX('other_sheet'!D:D, MATCH(A1&B1,'other_sheet'!A:A&'other_sheet'!B:B,0))
```

where 'other_sheet'!A:A, 'other_sheet'!B:B, and 'other_sheet'!D:D might also be a range like 'other_sheet'!A1:A100, 'other_sheet'!B1:B100 and 'other_sheet'!D1:D100.

Comment: That is right, except for the fact OP mentioned *without concatenation* ;). Concatenation may sometimes be a bit tricky and cause false positives. In the case of OP I don't think it would.

Comment: Hey @JvdV - that's what I thought as well. It looked to me that the issue was to replace VLOOKUP with INDEX MATCH and keep the concatenation. By the way, I still do not have LAMBDA, BYCOL, etc. Really frustrating.  It may be my o365 account.

Comment: For me in was an option to just join the beta, then update office and boom, they are there.

Comment: Ahh OK @JvdV  - I have two accounts, but primarily use my corp account, which may not be allowed to use Early Adopters. But now I understand how you have it.